# How to add multiple email address recipients retrieved from MySQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, email

I'm getting an error on this line below:

```
email = myDataReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
```

What I'm trying to do is just retrieve multiple email addresses from MySQL and send email.

Based on the example that I have found, it stores in the arraylist, but in my case it gives me error.

```
protected void searchEmail ()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=obsystem");
    con.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT cusEmail,cusFName,newBalance FROM monthlytracker WHERE MONTH(paymentDate)='" + mm + "' AND YEAR(paymentDate)='" + year + "'AND status='" + Unpaid + "'",con);

    MySqlDataReader myDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //ArrayList list_emails = new ArrayList();

    int i = 0;
    //string email = string.Empty;

    List<CustInfo> list_emails = new List<CustInfo>();

    CustInfo customer;

    while (myDataReader.Read())
    {
        //list_emails.Add(myDataReader.GetValue(i).ToString());//add to array list
        //i = i++; //increment or ++i

        list_emails.Add(new CustInfo
        {
            Email = myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
            Name = myDataReader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
            Balance = myDataReader.GetValue(2).ToString()
        });
    }

    con.Close(); //Close connection

    foreach (CustInfo cus in list_emails)
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("veolbakhda@gmail.com", "Shilpesh");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(cus.Email);
        const string fromPassword = "XXXXXXXX";
        string fullSubj = "Payment Reminder - Madu D. Trading (" + month + " , " + year + ")";
        //const string subject = fullSubj;
        //const string body = "Body";
        string body1 = cus.Name;
        string body2 = cus.Balance;
        string bodyfull = body1 + body2;

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = fullSubj,
            Body = bodyfull
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure `i = i + 1 - 1;` increment `i` variable???!!!

Comment: Please paste your error information here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the variable email as int

```
int i = 0, email = 0;
```

and then you try to store a string:

```
email = myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

Declare the variable email as string:

```
string email = string.Empty;
```

and you don't need the i variable:

```
int i = 0
```

and

```
i = i + 1 - 1; //increment or ++i
```

can be removed

Edit after comment:
You create a class for the customer information. I don't know how your fields are called, but say they are `cusName` and `balance`, you would do something like this:

```
public class CustInfo {
public string Email {get; set;}
public string Name  {get; set;}
public string Balance {get; set;}
}


protected void searchEmail ()
{
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=obsystem");
 con.Open();

 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT cusEmail, cusName, balance from monthlytracker AND MONTH(paymentDate)='" + mm + "' AND YEAR(paymentDate)='" + year + "'AND status='" + Unpaid + "'",con);

 MySqlDataReader myDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 List<CustInfo> list_emails = new List<CustInfo>();

 CustInfo customer;

 while (myDataReader.Read())
    {
        list_emails.Add(new CustInfo {
                          Email = myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                          Name =  myDataReader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                          Balance = myDataReader.GetValue(2).ToString() 
                        });
    }

    con.Close(); //Close connection 


    foreach (CustInfo customer in list_emails)

    {

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.To.Add(customer.Email);

        mail.Subject = "Welcome to C#";

        mail.From = new MailAddress("");

        mail.Body = "Test";

        // add the values from the customer object to your mail => fe: mail.Body.Replace("$$name$$", customer.Name);

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("SMTP Server");

        smtp.Send(mail);

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited according to what you have suggested, but when I have multiple email receipients, it gives the below error : System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Ye, you don't need the i variable, it's always 0. Edited my answer.

Comment: Btw,I would like to ask how would my MySQL select statement and array list be, if together with the email, i would also like to select the customer name field, and payment balance field ?

Comment: Stephen, excellent it works. Well, could you suggest to me how to I have a standard template to send to customers ? Currently, if you do notice, I'm just sending the "Test" to clients. I would like to have a standard template where it is able to append the name and balance according to the customer respectively from the class tht's created earlier together with some default text message. I will re-edit the code for you to have a better look. Thanks

Comment: I did read somewhere tht it uses html template. I tried and in the email, it comes along with the html tags.

Comment: add 'mail.IsBodyHtml = true;' before setting the 'mail.Body' should help with that

Comment: I dont think now tht's going to work as I kind of edited my codes as above. There's no more 'mail.Body' as I have already change it to into a group.

Comment: add `IsBodyHtml = true,` above `Body = bodyfull` in your new code

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Manage to do it successfulyy :D

Answer (score 0):

your code should be

```
 while (myDataReader.Read())
    {

        list_emails.Add(myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());//add to array list            
    }
```

Comment: I would like to ask how would my MySQL select statement and array list be, if together with the email, i would also like to select the customer name, and payment balance ?

Comment: then you need to create a class containing three things email, customername and payment balance. and in an array list you can add your class then